# Autoinstall of Microsoft Security Essentials give random error message

Tags: windows-xp, automated-install

I'm using wpkg to auto install Microsoft security essentials on WinXP. At the first login after the installer finishes I get an error message as msseces.exe starts. After a reboot the message goes away. The error message indicates a random access restriction.

"An error has occured in the program. Try to open it again. If this problem continues, you'll need to reinstall Microsoft Security Essentials from the Microsoft Download Center. Error code: 0x80070005"

Firstly: Does anyone know why I get this error message?

Second: How do I debug this kind of problems? The event log doesn't seem to contain anything useful. Is there a tool to detect and list denied system calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was solved by setting the flag "don't automatically run the updater and the system scan after installation"

I still don't know how to debug these problems, but that's really another story.